# What am I doing wrong to find element occurring most in array?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am trying to debug one online coding platform problem. The problem I am facing is to return element occurring most often in array. I am interested in correcting my current code than trying other methods.

```
function findMostOccured(M, A) { //value of elements in A should not be greater than M
    var N = A.length;
    var count = new Array(M + 1);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= M; i++)
        count[i] = 0;
    var maxOccurence = 1;
    var index = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (count[A[i]] > 0) {
            var tmp = count[A[i]];
            if (tmp > maxOccurence) {
                maxOccurence = tmp;
                index = i;
            }
            count[A[i]] = tmp + 1;
        } else {
            count[A[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return A[index];
}
```

Given `M = 3` and `A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1]`. It should return 3 or 1.

Comment: Your code looks correct and returns the right answer. What do you wish to be corrected?

Comment: It isn't correct. That's the issue. There's bug I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1];
var M = 3;

function findMostOccured(M, arr) {
  var obj = {};
  var result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (obj[arr[i]]) {
      obj[arr[i]] = obj[arr[i]] + 1;
    } else {
      obj[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === M) {
      result.push(parseInt(key));
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(findMostOccured(3, arr));
```

Comment: This solution also solves the problem with Linear time complexity that is O(n).